# Why not all values sink when using concurrent receive on queue

Tags: swift, combine

I'm learning Combine. I'm trying to understand some behavior when there is concurrent queue applied to receive on values. I extracted code to present the situation that I'm trying to understand.

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.global() // Or OperationQueue()
let subscription = (1...10).publisher
    .receive(on: queue)
    .sink { value in
        print("Received \(value)")
    }
```

I'm receiving in debug console such output:

```
Received 1
Received 2
Received 3
Received 7
Received 6
```

But I was expecting 10 lines. Everytime I run it I'm receiving different result but not 10 lines - 10 values. What is happening here? Does anybody know? Where is 4, 5, 8, 9 and 10?

Comment: Concurrent queues cannot be used as schedulers. If you add a print statement for receiving completion you will see that the stream completes before emitting all values

Comment: Any Apple documentation saying that we can't count on Concurrent queues?

Comment: @LuLuGaGa It would be helpful to expand this into a full answer. After many years of working with Combine, I do know this doesn't work, and I have some vague ideas of what's actually happening, but I certainly would consider it common sense. I couldn't easily answer why this doesn't work. If you have an obvious answer, it would be very good to capture that here for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.print()` to understand what is going on, so

```
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global() // Or OperationQueue()
    let subscription = (1...10).publisher
    .receive(on: queue)
    .print()
    .sink { value in
        print("Received \(value)")
    }
```

gives an output like this:

```
receive subscription: (ReceiveOn)
request unlimited
receive value: (2)
Received 2
receive value: (10)
Received 10
receive value: (3)
Received 3
receive value: (6)
Received 6
receive value: (4)
Received 4
receive finished
receive value: (9)
receive value: (8)
receive value: (1)
receive value: (7)
receive value: (5)
```

Which tells us that we receive some values after we received completion event, which is normal, since `DispatchQueue.global()` can execute the operations on different queues for concurrency purposes, and they come back in different time and order.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the main queue

```swift
let queue = DispatchQueue.main
```

Or create your own queue.

```swift
let queue = DispatchQueue.init(label: "customQueue")
```

Since predefined queues as `global` queue will use multiple threads. So if you want to ensure that they will be received together I recommend creating your own queue.

Comment: I believe the question is why this doesn't receive all items in parallel, rather than how to make it serial.